# Which tool to use for MS Access to SQL Server migration? SQL Server Data Import Wizard Vs. SSMA Vs. SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, data-migration

I'm new to Microsoft world. I've been tasked with migrating an MS Access 2007 database to SQL Server 2012 database. It will be a one time migration for a client, that will be using SQL Server 2012 moving forward and will drop MS Access from their ecosystem.

Currently, MS Access database has 300 or so tables, with almost no pk/fk connections between tables. A lot of data is replicated within and across the tables. I don't have to redesign the database or normalize it in any way (although looking at it I am itching to do it,but will not). It also has a lot of queries, modules, and macros, along with forms and reports.

While reading about this task at hand and researching online, I came across three possible solutions. Since I have limited experience in db world, I'll need some guidance as to what the pros/cons of each option will be for this specific scenario?

1. Use SQL Server data import wizard. This seems like a good option. It is easy to use and the task is one time only. Not sure if it will import other objects too (queries etc.).
2. SSMA is another option, not sure how it is different than the data import wizard.
3. A colleague suggested SSIS for the task. To me it seems like an overkill, but I don't know enough to make this judgement.

What I'm looking for is some advice on which of these options to use from someone who has done something similar (which I think is not a rare task), to share their experience and industry best practice.

Comment: SQL Server data import wizard will basically create an SSIS package. If you need to test and maybe re-run your migration it would be wise to save the package created by the data import wizard to re-use it.

Comment: Will it import the queries and other object too?

Comment: I'm not really sure what query objects will map to in SQL Server but you will of course loose any Forms and other UI related objects because the have no counterpart in SQL Server. You will have to try and start with Data Import Wizard.

Comment: tables and queries only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **One-off migrations?** - use the SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) or the SQL Server Import Wizard.
- **Repeated, scheduled migrations?** - use SQL Server Integration Services. It provides better scripting support that will allow you to repeat the same process to your heart's content.

Between SSMA and SQL Server Import Wizard however, I would recommend SSMA. Not only is it streamlined and straightforward, it provides better support for migrating all your objects from an Access database (Tables and queries) to SQL Server. You can follow this tutorial for learning how to do this: http://sqlturbo.com/from-access-to-sql-with-microsoft-sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access/